# (Google Analytics) View filter with two conditions

Tags: filter, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm facing a small issue with pingdom-like services.

I cannot exclude them from analytics with filter since I would need two apply that filter based on two different variables.

The problem is that there's a lot of other traffic from same ISP and also from same network.
Therefore I cannot make two filters for both ISP and network since it would exclude valid traffic from analytics results.

All in all I only want to exclude traffic that matches both variables ISP and network.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

**First filter**

Custom > Advanced

Field A > ISP Organization > (.*)

Output to > Custom Field 1 > $A1

**Second filter**

Custom > Advanced

Field A > Hostname > (.*)

Field B > Custom Field 1 > (.*)

Output to > Custom Field 1 > Hostname:$A1 ISP:$B1

**Third filter**

Exclude 
Custom Field 1 > Hostname:hostname.com ISP:Your ISP

Answer (score 0):

Can you determine in your app logic whether or not the hit is coming from the services?  If you can, you could set up a custom dimension in GA and filter out traffic based on the custom dimension values.